# How to load list view selected item should be middle of visible position in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell How to implement while loading the list view I want to display selected item in centre position in android

I have five image in my list view if user select 4th image  in first time.I am saving selected position in db.if second time user come I need to show the 4 th image in center of visible position of list view

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you please give a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more details. I think you can do this bu using a custom adapter.